# mysql - skip duplicates while update

Tags: mysql

I am working on a Java project in which I manage students

Each student has the following attributes :

- ID INT (PK)
- First_Name VARCHAR
- Last_Name VARCHAR
- Email  VARCHAR (UNIQUE)
- Phone_Number VARCHAR (UNIQUE)

Suppose I want to update this student :

```
UPDATE student SET First_Name='John',Last_Name='Doe',Email='john.doe@gmail.com',Phone_Number='0612345678' WHERE id=25
```

If the email or the phone_number already exist, the query fails and I would like to know if there's a way to make MySQL update only the fields which are not duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks. Now if I use ignore and the query contains duplicate entry, will it update only the other fields or the whole query is discared ?

Comment: Sorry just modified my answer, this is what you want commonly know as an UPSET (combo update / insert)